# Android application is not running in KitKat

Tags: java, android, android-version, android-compatibility

I have developed an app. I was testing this app with my Jellybean device but now when I am checking it with KitKat device then it is not opening but in is working fine on lollipop device. I am posting my manifest file here.
Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.beproject.ourway"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:maxSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.beproject.ourway.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" >
    </permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.beproject.ourway.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my_api_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FriendsListActivity"
            android:label="Friends"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FormSignUp"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_form_sign_up"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FormSignIn"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_form_sign_in"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PassRecovery1"
            android:label="Recover Password"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PassRecovery2"
            android:label="Recover Password"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PassRecovery3"
            android:label="Recover Password"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUpVerify"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up_verify"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ProfileInfo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_profile_info"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeMap"
            android:label="OwrWay" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainHome"
            android:label="OwrWay"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Places"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_places"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AddPlace"
            android:label="Add Place"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditPlace"
            android:label="Edit Place"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Temp"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_temp" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Settings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Panic"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_panic"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post error log

Comment: android:maxSdkVersion and android:targetSdkVersion shouldn't be as high as it possible so 22 (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.1.html),  download the newest sdk to be sure that you can target it and make updates, maybe it will be helpful.

Comment: @MyWay I am not getting your answer

Comment: As you haven't posted a line of code, you'll just have to debug it yourself, which is the obvious way to track down nearly all problems.